# Is there a way to get a list of all service having a particular tag using either a python sdk or REST API calls?

Tags: python, azure

So, what I actually want to do is to delete a set of services that I have created, all of these services share a common tag, I don't want to use the CLI, cause I've been using REST API calls up until this point and I would like to keep it consistent.

I've looked up the Azure REST API documentation but couldn't find anything to help me with this.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using REST API, you can use [`Resources - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) API and filter the results by tag.

From the documentation link:

> Resources can be filtered by tag names and values. For example, to
> filter for a tag name and value, use $filter=tagName eq 'tag1' and
> tagValue eq 'Value1'. Note that when resources are filtered by tag
> name and value, the original tags for each resource will not be
> returned in the results. Any list of additional properties queried via
> $expand may also not be compatible when filtering by tag names/values.

Your request would be something like:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2021-04-01&$filter=tagName eq 'tag1' and tagValue eq 'Value1'
```